# What will be query for popular tags in blog implementation?

Tags: mysql, sql

What will be query for popular tags?
**Tabels**

```
blog_tags
id  name
1   tag1
2   tag2
3   tag3
4   tag4
5   tag5




blog_post_tags
id  post_id     blog_tag_id
1   1       2
2   2       2
3   1       3
4   3       5
5   4       2



output
tag2
tag3
tag5
```

**I started the query writing like this:**

```
SELECT bt.id, bt.name, bpt.blog_tag_id
FROM
blog_tags bt
RIGHT JOIN
blog_post_tags bpt
ON
bt.id = bpt.blog_tag_id
ORDER BY bt.name ASC
```

It gives me output of the tags which used in blog_post_tags, but i want that the tags get sorted according to popularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace you `right join` to `inner join`, and `group by` tag id like this:

```
select bt.name
from blog_post_tags bpt
join blog_tags bt on bpt.blog_tag_id = bt.id
group by bt.id, bt.name -- Edit: fixing for some strict dbs
order by count(bpt.post_id) desc
```

See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fae94c/1) in sqlfiddle.

Comment: This is invalid grouping, another most strict DB than mysql, will raise error for this query

Comment: @OtoShavadze Which kind of db? Please tell me. I'll check it.

Comment: @Forward Why we need order by **post_id** ? I just changed it to **blog_tag_id** and it is working fine.

Comment: @Forward - For example in oracle DB or in postgres

Comment: @VBMali blog_tag_id is also correct. Even if `count(1)`.

Comment: @OtoShavadze The query is working fine in **PostgreSQL**

Comment: @VBMali - Which version of PostgreSQL  do you have ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze **9.5.6**
PostgreSQL 9.5.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit

Comment: @VBMali - and you don't get following error:   `column "bt.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` ?

Comment: @You guys two, What if I add `bt.name` in `group by`? :) @Oto Shavadze thank for your strict.

Comment: @OtoShavadze, sorry, I already made that corrections in my query, forgot to correct here.

Answer (score 1):

i think query like this should work :

```
select name from (select blog_tag_id,count(*) as cnt from blog_post_tags group by blog_tag_id order by cnt dsc ) as a inner join blog_tags on a.blog_tag_id = blog_tags.id
```

Comment: This is also accepted answer, but as my DB structure having some composite keys, that's why it is throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  blog_tags.name, t.used_cnt FROM blog_tags
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT blog_tag_id, count(*)  as used_cnt
    from blog_post_tags
    group by blog_tag_id 
)t 
ON blog_tags.id = t.blog_tag_id
ORDER BY t.used_cnt DESC
```

Comment: Please do some elaborate for your answer, a good answer not just code.

Comment: @Forward - So, in inner query, there is counted `blog_tag_id` values by grouping, and then, this counted data joined to `blog_tags` table and ordered by `count desc`

Comment: No, not comment, I mean your answer. :) And it is not I don't understand your answer, it just lack of some explanation.

Comment: And also, your code is definitely right. I mean it.